# Permuted combinations of the elements of a list - Prolog

Tags: prolog

How can I generate all the possible combinations of the elements of a list?

For example, given the list `[1,2,3]`, I want to design a predicate with the form `comb([1,2,3], L).` which should return the following answer for `L`:

```
[1]  
[2]  
[3]  
[1,2]  
[2,1]  
[1,3]  
[3,1]  
[2,3] 
[3,2]  
[1,2,3]  
[1,3,2]  
[2,1,3]  
[2,3,1]  
[3,1,2]  
[3,2,1]
```

Comment: [1] isn't usually called a combination of [1,2,3]: I'm guessing this isn't what you mean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are asking for involves both combinations (selecting a subset) and permutations (rearranging the order) of a list.

Your example output implies that the empty list is not considered a valid solution, so we will exclude it in the implementation that follows.  Reconsider if this was an oversight.  Also this implementation produces the solutions in a different order than your example output.

```
comb(InList,Out) :-
    splitSet(InList,_,SubList),
    SubList = [_|_],     /* disallow empty list */
    permute(SubList,Out).

splitSet([ ],[ ],[ ]).
splitSet([H|T],[H|L],R) :-
    splitSet(T,L,R).
splitSet([H|T],L,[H|R]) :-
    splitSet(T,L,R).

permute([ ],[ ]) :- !.
permute(L,[X|R]) :-
    omit(X,L,M),
    permute(M,R).

omit(H,[H|T],T).
omit(X,[H|L],[H|R]) :-
    omit(X,L,R).
```

Tested with Amzi! Prolog:

```
?- comb([1,2,3],L).

L = [3] ;

L = [2] ;

L = [2, 3] ;

L = [3, 2] ;

L = [1] ;

L = [1, 3] ;

L = [3, 1] ;

L = [1, 2] ;

L = [2, 1] ;

L = [1, 2, 3] ;

L = [1, 3, 2] ;

L = [2, 1, 3] ;

L = [2, 3, 1] ;

L = [3, 1, 2] ;

L = [3, 2, 1] ;
no
```

Comment: What is this `!` for?

Comment: @false: I think there is only one cut, in the first clause for `permute/2`, and this is for efficiency  (aka "green cut").

Comment: Red usage: `permute(Xs, Ys), Xs = [_]`

Comment: @false:  I think your observation is more about my predicate `permute/2` not supporting uninstantiated first arguments.  The Question concerns how to produce "all the possible combinations of the elements of a list" ... "given the list", so my implementation was aimed at efficiency for that mode.  See the [SWI-Prolog notation description](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=preddesc) for mode indicators.

Comment: You are right, but still your answer contains this problematic code.

Comment: @false: I think I would get a better understanding of your point of view in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84220/discussion-between-false-and-hardmath).

Answer (score 5):

Stay pure by defining `comb/2` based on [`same_length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=same_length/2), [`prefix/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=prefix/2), [`foldl/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4) and 
[`select/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3):

```
comb(As,Bs) :-
   same_length(As,Full),
   Bs = [_|_],
   prefix(Bs,Full),
   foldl(select,Bs,As,_).
```

Here's the sample query given by the OP:

```
?- comb([1,2,3],Xs).
  Xs = [1]
; Xs = [2]
; Xs = [3]
; Xs = [1,2]
; Xs = [1,3]
; Xs = [2,1]
; Xs = [2,3]
; Xs = [3,1]
; Xs = [3,2]
; Xs = [1,2,3]
; Xs = [1,3,2]
; Xs = [2,1,3]
; Xs = [2,3,1]
; Xs = [3,1,2]
; Xs = [3,2,1]
; false.
```

Ok! But what if the list given as the first argument contains duplicates?

```
?- comb([1,1,2],Xs).
  Xs = [1]
; Xs = [1]                   % (redundant)
; Xs = [2]
; Xs = [1,1]
; Xs = [1,2]
; Xs = [1,1]                 % (redundant)
; Xs = [1,2]                 % (redundant)
; Xs = [2,1]
; Xs = [2,1]                 % (redundant)
; Xs = [1,1,2]
; Xs = [1,2,1]
; Xs = [1,1,2]               % (redundant)
; Xs = [1,2,1]               % (redundant)
; Xs = [2,1,1]
; Xs = [2,1,1]               % (redundant)
; false.
```

*Not quite!* Can we get rid of above redundant answers? Yes, simply use [`selectd/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30207770/4609915)!

```
comb(As,Bs) :-
   same_length(As,Full),
   Bs = [_|_],
   prefix(Bs,Full),
   foldl(selectd,Bs,As,_).
```

So let's re-run above query again with the improved implementation of `comb/2`!

```
?- comb([1,1,2],Xs).
  Xs = [1]
; Xs = [2]
; Xs = [1,1]
; Xs = [1,2]
; Xs = [2,1]
; Xs = [1,1,2]
; Xs = [1,2,1]
; Xs = [2,1,1]
; false.
```

Comment: Great solution, +1! I hope we will soon see a library containing all these pure elementary predicates! `library(purple)`: *Pure Prolog Library (Elementary)*?

Comment: Note: This also needs `:- use_module(library(lists)).` and [if_/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/1243762)

Comment: @GuyCoder. You're right. The dependency on `if_/3` is not immediately visible, but I'm linking to the definition of `selectd/3`... good enough?

Comment: @GuyCoder. What would you suggest? The asker might want to get self-contained answers to reproduce experiments (shown in an answer) easily. But how to do that (with different Prolog systems, libraries, etc.)?

Comment: The reason I looked at this answer is because I am generating data for test cases and while combinations and permutations work fine when I have 3 or more items in the set, when there is only 2 items in the set and I need to generate a pattern with 3 items, how do I extend the set. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42233085/1243762) appears to have what I seek, Just need to check it now.

Answer (score 2):

there is a predefined predicate called permutation  ...

```
1 ?- permutation([1,2,3],L).
L = [1, 2, 3] ;
L = [2, 1, 3] ;
L = [2, 3, 1] ;
L = [1, 3, 2] ;
L = [3, 1, 2] ;
L = [3, 2, 1] .

2 ?- listing(permutation).
lists:permutation([], [], []).
lists:permutation([C|A], D, [_|B]) :-
        permutation(A, E, B),
        select(C, D, E).

lists:permutation(A, B) :-
        permutation(A, B, B).

true.
```

hope this helps ..

Comment: It's definitely helpful for seeing how one can go about describing permutations (+1!). An instructive feature of this code is that `permutation/3` is *not* tail recursive, and that exchanging the two goals typically increases runtime by a large margin. It's also elegant and nice to look at, involving only pure code. Note though that OP asks for something slightly different: The question is about permutations of subsequences, not necessarily comprising the whole list. Check out @repeat's short, elegant and pure solution!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: This is easy to do if you have written a predicate `inselt(X,Y,Z)`, which holds if any insertion of `Y` into `X` gives `Z`:

```
inselt([E|X], Y, [E|Z]) :- inselt(X,Y,Z).
inselt(X, Y, [Y|X]).
```

Then `comb/3` can be coded recursively using `inselt/3`.