# All subset of list with k elements in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Please help me to solve this problem:

> subset(N, [1,2,3], L).

if N=2, I want the result is that:

> [1,2];
>
> [2,1];
>
> [1,3];
>
> [3,1];
>
> [2,3];
>
> [3,2];

(in any order)

Comment: if it's homework please tag as such

Comment: select/3 it's the builtin that can help you to solve this little problem

Comment: Please, don't just post your assignment, but show some effort. What have you tried?

Comment: My solution: <br /> subset(0, _, []). <br />
subset(N, [X | T], [X | R]) :- N > 0, N1 is N - 1, subset(N1, T, R). <br />
subset(N, [_ | T], R) :- N > 0, subset(N, T, R). <br /> The result is that: <br /> [1,2];[1,3];[2,3];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your base case is trivial:

```
subset(0,Lst,[]).
```

If N>0, you have 2 choices as to what to do with the first element of Lst:

1. You can ignore it, and look for your subset in what remains of Lst
2. You can include it in your subset, adding it to what you get for a 1-smaller subset of what remains of Lst.

You might think you have to worry about Lst being too short (or N being too big: same thing), but if you've coded the above properly, it should be taken care of for you.

Hoep that's enough to get you started.

Comment: My solution: <br/> subset(0, _, []). <br/>
subset(N, [X | T], [X | R]) :- N > 0, N1 is N - 1, subset(N1, T, R). <br/>
subset(N, [_ | T], R) :- N > 0, subset(N, T, R). <br/> The result is that: <br/> [1,2];[1,3];[2,3];

Comment: The result from your solution looks like it has what you originally said you needed, except for the reversed-duplicates.  If you still need them, you'll need a rule that produces the reverse of what you produce now.

Comment: I tried to reverse my list with SWI-Prolog built-in predicate reverse. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "doesn't work", but even if it did, it wouldn't solve the problem for N>2.  What you need is instead of always taking the first element of the list out, you need to take an arbitrary element out so that all permutations will be possible.

Answer (score 2):

I rewrite this solution: (based on: [Permuted combinations of the elements of a list - Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578755/combinations-of-the-elements-of-a-list-prolog))

```
subset(N, InList, Out) :-
    splitSet(InList,_,SubList),
    permutation(SubList,Out),
    length(Out, N).

splitSet([ ],[ ],[ ]).
splitSet([H|T],[H|L],R) :-
    splitSet(T,L,R).
splitSet([H|T],L,[H|R]) :-
    splitSet(T,L,R).
```

The result (tested in SWI-Prolog):

```
?- subset(2,[1,2,3],R).
R = [2, 3] ;
R = [3, 2] ;
R = [1, 3] ;
R = [3, 1] ;
R = [1, 2] ;
R = [2, 1] ;
false.
```