# Predicate arithmetic combination (only + or -) to find a result from a list of numbers

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to achieve an old exercice from my school and i can't figure it out how to solve it. Here is the result expected :

> bC([1,12,34,23,11],23,Res).
>
> Res = 1+11-12+23

So `bC/3` is supposed to find every combination of addition or substract operation (the third argument) from a list of number (the first argument) to match a result (the second argument).

I can't find a way to start resolving this... If someone could give me a clue about this problem, i would really appreciate it.

UPDATE: Some elements of the list can be left out.

Comment: You can try to construct all *syntax* trees exhaustively, and each time verify if the result is the requested result.

Comment: So some elements can be left out (here `34`)? or is that a mistake?

Comment: Yes, some elements can be left out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a **hint**: you can aim to construct all expressions by exhautively searching over the expression space. Since `X - (Y - Z)` is just `X - Y + Z`, this is good news, since we can restrict us to *left recursive* expressions, like:

```
makepm([], ExpI, ExpI).
makepm([H|T], ExpI, ExpO) :-
    makepm(T, +(ExpI, H), ExpO).
makepm([H|T], ExpI, ExpO) :-
    makepm(T, -(ExpI, H), ExpO).
```

If as first element we take `1`, and we inject the rest of the list in the `makepm/3`, we get:

```
?- makepm([12,34,23,11], 1, F).
F = 1+12+34+23+11 ;
F = 1+12+34+23-11 ;
F = 1+12+34-23+11 ;
F = 1+12+34-23-11 ;
F = 1+12-34+23+11 ;
F = 1+12-34+23-11 ;
F = 1+12-34-23+11 ;
F = 1+12-34-23-11 ;
F = 1-12+34+23+11 ;
F = 1-12+34+23-11 ;
F = 1-12+34-23+11 ;
F = 1-12+34-23-11 ;
F = 1-12-34+23+11 ;
F = 1-12-34+23-11 ;
F = 1-12-34-23+11 ;
F = 1-12-34-23-11.
```

**What still needs to be done**: the question is not perfectly clear about the fact if numbers can be left out, if that is the case, then you should write a predicate that first selects a subset of numbers. Then we can exhaustively enumerate all expressions which we create with `makepm/3`, and then we need to verify, for example with the [**`is/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2) predicate that the expression sums up to the requested value. If that is the case the predicate can succeed.

Comment: That's a very good hint :). I will try to use your predicate with what i've found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578755/permuted-combinations-of-the-elements-of-a-list-prolog to get all possible permuted combination. I begin to understand how i have to think to resolve this kind of problems now...